# How can I avoid duplicates when storing a set of key-value pairs in an RDBMS as an opaque String / Blob?

Tags: database-design, data-structures, dictionary

I'm trying to decide how I should store a set of key-value pairs (Strings) in a DB. The classical approach would look something like this, using two tables:

```
  +-------------+
  | PropertySet |
  +-------------+
  | set_id      |
  | property_id |
  | value       |
  +-------------+

  +-------------+
  | Property    |
  +-------------+
  | property_id |
  | name        |
  +-------------+
```

Now, for my purpose, this seems slightly overkill. I'm hardly going to use SQL to work with this data and I would like to avoid the more complex queries required in this design. I probably prefer storing a JSON or protobuf blob with an id, like so:

```
  +-------------+
  | PropertySet |
  +-------------+
  | set_id      |
  | data        |
  +-------------+
```

However, I want to ensure that there are no duplicates. I could imagine ordering the set by key names, normalize the format and then do a string comparison. Are there alternatives?

I also appreciate advice on the actual design question (relational database vs blobs), but maybe that should go into comments.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few thoughts on this:

- Blob colums will tend to be slower as blobs are stored separately from the table data in most databases.
- You will need the property key to form a part of the database key for the properties table if you want the database to ensure uniqueness, so you will need a structure like the Property/PropertySet tables as described in the post to get an integrity constraint out of the database.
- In any but trivial cases you are probably not the only one who will be querying the database.  Encoding the data in opaque structures makes it much harder for third parties to use the data.
- The property set/property table will be reasonably efficient to query, particularly on a platform that supports clustered indexes.

If you want to get integrity out of the database system you will have to play by its rules.  The only other option is to enforce it programatically upstream of the database.

Programatically picking apart the property set and sorting it to spot duplicates seems at least as complex as querying the joined PropertySet/Property structure, so I doubt you're really saving yourself effort by flattening it anyway.  Either case requires you to convert it into a structure with the key/value pairs - it's probably easier just to load and store them as such and the database will be much more accessible to third parties.

Comment: Third parties are not my concern, but your points are good ones nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I've thought about this problem before but have never tried to implement a solution so take my suggestion with a grain of salt.

What if you generate a hash for the data, you can then store the hash in the table in a unique index.

Comment: yes it is possible to have duplicates, however if you use the hash value to limit the potential duplicates then you'd only have to compare the actual values where they have the same hash value